# How can you access the radio input value from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get the value with JavaScript from HTML Code Example below?

```
<input type="radio" name="question1" value=1> Choose me <br/>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value=2> Or me! <br/>
```

Can I use this? And how can I change it, that if I had 3 sets of radio inputs, that JavaScript can add the value of the user inputs?

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].getAttribute("value"); 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getValues() {

var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value; 
document.getElementById("feedback_1").innerHTML = x;

var y = document.querySelector('input[name="group"]:checked').value;

document.getElementById("feedback_2").innerHTML = y;

};
```

```html
<h3>Input</h3>
<input type="radio" value="First value" name="single" id="myInput" checked>1</input>
<hr>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="group">1</input>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="group">2</input>
<input type="radio" value="3" name="group" checked>3</input>

<p><button onclick="getValues();">Get values</button></p>

<h3>Your selection</h3>
<p id="feedback_1"></p>
<p id="feedback_2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=question1]');

radios.forEach((radio)=>{
  radio.addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e.target.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="question1" value=1> Choose me <br/>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value=2> Or me! <br/>
<p id="demo"></p>
```